# создание изображения в php

Tags: php

```
<?

Header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

if (@($f)):

$width=500;

$height=40;

else:

$width=500;

$height=300;

endif;

$image = imagecreate($width, $height);

// allocate colors

$color_backgr = imagecolorallocate($image, 200, 200, 55);

$color_grid = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

$color_plot = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0);

// clear image

imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $width - 1, $height - 1, $color_backgr);

// draw axes

imagerectangle($image, 0, 0, $width - 1, $height - 1, $color_plot);

// print some text

imagestring($image, 5, 20, 7,$string, $color_grid);


imagejpeg($image);

imagedestroy($image);

?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Лабораторная работа #3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="center">
   <?

echo "<H1 align=center> Лабораторна робота №3 </H1>";

?>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">

        <input type="submit" value="Small" name="sub">
        <input type="submit" value="BIG" name="unsub">


</form>

       <?
        if (@($unsub)):
        unset($sub);
        endif;
        if (!@($sub)):

    printf("<img src='l3.php'>");

     else:           

   printf("<img src='l3.php?f=1'>");
     endif;          
    ?>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Перенесите, пожалуйста, свой комментарий в вопрос.